# Matplotlib scatterplot axis autoscale fails for small data values

Tags: python, matplotlib

When using Matplotlib's `scatterplot`, sometimes autoscaling works, sometimes not.

How do I fix it?

As in the example provided in the bug report, this code works:

```
plt.figure()
x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
x = np.array([2,4,5,9])
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

But when using smaller values, the scaling fails to work:

```
plt.figure()
x = np.array([0,1,2,3])
x = np.array([2,4,5,9])
plt.scatter(x/10000,y/10000)
```

Edit: An example can be found [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6015). I have not specified the specific cause in the question, because when encountering the error it is not obvious what causes it. Also, I have specified the solution and cause in my own answer.

Comment: What do you mean by `sometimes`? Demonstrate it with some examples

Comment: I've edited the question with a link to an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In at least Matplotlib 1.5.1, there is a bug where autoscale fails for small data values, as reported [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6015).

The workaround is to use `.set_ylim(bottom,top)` ([documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html)) to manually set the data limits (in this example for the y axis, to set the x axis, use `.set_xlim(left,right)`.

To automatically find the data limits that are pleasing to the eyes, the following pseudocode can be used:

```
def set_axlims(series, marginfactor):
    """
    Fix for a scaling issue with matplotlibs scatterplot and small values.
    Takes in a pandas series, and a marginfactor (float).
    A marginfactor of 0.2 would for example set a 20% border distance on both sides.
    Output:[bottom,top]
    To be used with .set_ylim(bottom,top)
    """
    minv = series.min()
    maxv = series.max()
    datarange = maxv-minv
    border = abs(datarange*marginfactor)
    maxlim = maxv+border
    minlim = minv-border

    return minlim,maxlim
```