# Matplotlib's autoscale doesn't seem to work on y axis for small values?

Tags: python, matplotlib

For some reason, plt.autoscale does not seem to work for very small values (i.e. something like 1E-05). Everything is just displayed close to the zero axis in the graph as shown.

Any ideas where I am going wrong here?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y=  [1.09E-05,  1.63E-05,   2.45E-05,   3.59E-05,   5.09E-05,   6.93E-05,   9.07E-05]
x=  [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
ax3.scatter(x, y, color='k', marker = "o")
ax3 = plt.gca()
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis="y", tight=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe this is [a known issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/6015) which is still not solved in matplotlib. It is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674917/animation-in-matplotlib-with-scatter-and-using-set-offsets-autoscale-of-figure) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634370/matplotlib-scatterplot-axis-autoscale-fails-for-small-data-values).

Possible solutions for this case would be

**Use `plot`** instead of `scatter`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y=  [1.09E-05,  1.63E-05,   2.45E-05,   3.59E-05,   5.09E-05,   6.93E-05,   9.07E-05]
x=  [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
ax3.plot(x, y, color='k', marker = "o", ls="")
ax3.autoscale(enable=True, axis="y", tight=False)
plt.show()
```

**Use invisible `plot` in addition to `scatter`**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y=  [1.09E-05,  1.63E-05,   2.45E-05,   3.59E-05,   5.09E-05,   6.93E-05,   9.07E-05]
x=  [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
ax3.scatter(x, y, color='k', marker = "o")
ax3.plot(x, y, color='none')
ax3.relim()
ax3.autoscale_view()
plt.show()
```

**Manually scale the axis** using `set_ylim`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y=  [1.09E-05,  1.63E-05,   2.45E-05,   3.59E-05,   5.09E-05,   6.93E-05,   9.07E-05]
x=  [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
ax3.scatter(x, y, color='k', marker = "o")

dy = (max(y) - min(y))*0.1
ax3.set_ylim(min(y)-dy, max(y)+dy)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I did not know this was already asked before. Thank you for providing an informative answer nonetheless!

Answer (score 3):

Just to add an update here to anyone who finds this post in the future - it has now been resolved in matplotlib 3.2.1. Just update your package and it should work.

Comment: I tried this with my data and I got the same result as @bwrr. The solution for me was to use plot (is mentioned by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest) instead of scatter, with parameters `marker = "o", ls=""`

Not sure if this issue has been fixed in matplotlib for scatter?